# asynchronous functions of type void in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

I have a problem and would be grateful if anyone can help.
Working with asynchronous functions that have a "Promise" as a return is simple, but and when an asynchronous function has no return type, what is the correct way to work.

I have 2 "void" functions, and I need one to be executed only when the other is done. What is the correct way to do this?

The problem I am facing is as follows:
I'm working with React-native, and I have two variables that use state:

```
const [x, setX] = React.useState ("");
const [y, setY] = React.useState ("");
```

the value of variable "x" will be passed to variable "y", using the function setY (x); but before passing the value of the variable "x" to the variable "y" I make a change in the value of "x".

```
setX ("test");
setY (x);
```

And therein comes the problem, the functions that allow changing the values saved in the state are asynchronous functions without return. So I would like the setX ("test") function to be executed before the setY (x) function, but unfortunately I can't do that.
the value of the variable "x" is being passed to setY () as "", as this was the initial value given to it, and the updated value of "x" which in this case is "test", is arriving late in variable x .

Comment: If they don't emit an event of some kind or accept a callback, then there is no clean way. Either check the side effects it may have _(does is update some variable you have access to?)_, proxy one of the functions it may use internally _(hijack `$.ajax` to spy on it for example)_ or use a `setTimeout`...

Comment: Can you share your functions with us?

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf First thanks for your attention. I edited the post with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a promise:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

// add event handlers that call resolve and reject
// call your asynchronous function

}).then(...
```